# Timeout error with windowMaximize using Selenium RC

Tags: java, selenium-rc

I am trying to navigate to a page and maximize and focus the page..My code  is as below -.

```
public class DynamicTableHandling
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        Selenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost",4444,"*firefox","http://scores.sify.com"); 
        selenium.start();       
        selenium.open("/match/scorecard/ENG_IND_JUL27_JUL31_2014.shtml");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("180000");      
        selenium.windowMaximize();
        selenium.windowFocus();
    }
}
```

It opens up the URL but doesn maximize or focus the window. I have been working on gmail and other websites and there both the windowMAximize() and windowFocus were working perfectly. Moreover I am getting error as below:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: Timed out after 30000ms
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.throwAssertionFailureExceptionOrError(HttpCommandProcessor.java:109)
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.doCommand(HttpCommandProcessor.java:103)
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.open(DefaultSelenium.java:369)
    at DynamicTableHandling.main(DynamicTableHandling.java:13)
```

Comment: Looks like the `.open()` command failed.

Comment: Why Selenium-RC? It has been deprecated for several **years** now. Consider switching to Selenium-WebDriver.